# Query re Physics-related quote about the amount of energy in water

Tags: quote, energy

In [The Children's Encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Children%27s_Encyclop%C3%A6dia), edited by Arthur Mee which was in print from 1908 to 1964 (Vol 3, p 1614), there is an essay about Energy in which the following is asserted:

> A man of science once said that there was enough energy in a glass of
>   water to lift the whole of the Royal Navy into the air as high as St.
>   Paul's Cathedral.

Can anyone help me locate the source of this quote? Who stated this? When? In what context? I figure the quote has to date roughly post 1697 when the building was consecrated and sufficiently before 1908 to allow for writing, editing and publication. I also assume it would have been an English physicist or scientist, probably London-based, given the reference point to the cathedral.

Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is about history, not physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/should-history-of-physics-questions-be-on-topic), and as such it should be posted on [hsm.se]. (Please don't cross-post, though - flag for a moderator to migrate.)

Comment: That said, I feel it's quite likely that the 'man of science' the quote refers to is simply Einstein, through his identification of $E=mc^2$ in special relativity; the application to the glass of water and the Royal Navy is then a simple calculation that could well be due to Arthur Mee.

Comment: @Leon Conrad I like your attempts to narrow the field. Post 1905, certainly. Probably English, certainly British. Jeans, Eddington, or even Rutherford, E N da C Andrade spring to mind as possibles.

Comment: @PhilipWood and EmilioPisanty, thank you for your suggestions, but 1905-ish is ex-ante rather than my post-ante date. The quote must date from some time between 1697 and c 1905. Einstein is too late, unless the quote can be specifically dated. I think he published on special relativity in 1911, but I may be mistaken. Please feel free to migrate if you feel the need. Thanks. Leon

Comment: To me this has the ring of a twentieth century pronouncement but, more to the point, what does it mean? I'm sure no-one would have spoken  of the $energy$ in a glass of water before the work of Joule and others in the mid-nineteenth century. And to supply the amount of energy needed to lift the ships as stated one would make some inroads into the rest mass of the water, so I'm pretty sure that the 'man of science' is trying to explain the significance of $E=mc^2$. That would make it post-1905 (Einstein's Special Relativity paper published).

Comment: @PhilipWood - Thanks - I can't check the earlier editions at the moment, but the article repeats through the 1920s to the 1950s (I have 3 editions) and I suspect it would have been the same in the earlier editions. Either way, can you give some evidence to support your 'I'm pretty sure', which is just a guess at the moment. It would be nice to tie this down to the original source.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - topic is on hold at the moment. Would you be kind enough to migrate, so it can be viewed by more people? Thanks -

Comment: @LeonConrad I'm not a mod - you can raise them using the 'flag' link below the question tags.

Comment: Regarding the date, the $E=mc^2$ identification is dated to 1905; if there is some reason why that would be too late, that's not really in the question or your comments, so it'd be good to have on record.

Comment: And yes, the pointer to Einstein is indeed a guess, but there's very little else that can pack that kind of energy ─ lifting 100k tonnes by 100m takes about 1.2mg's worth of $mc^2$ equivalent, and none of the physical processes in the work of Joule and his contemporaries would be able to [pack](https://xkcd.com/1162/) that amount of energy into that little mass. As to whether the quote is by Mee or someone else, some additional context from the text around that quote would probably be quite helpful.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - Thanks for the 1905 date - I was confusing this paper with the General Relativity/Gravity paper of 1911. Unfortunately a web search, a PDF search on Google, and a Google book search for ["St Paul's Cathedral" + Einstien + Energy + Water] have not turned up anything - I suspect we're looking at an earlier date - from an English scientist, probably London-based.

Comment: Note that GR isn't from 1911 either ─ that's from 1915. If you came here for the physics insights, then the answer really is that there is nothing other than SR that would pack that much energy, and indeed pre-1905 the claim would've been laughed off immediately as ridiculous. I don't think you'll find a previous instance of that quote, it admits a clear reading as Mee paraphrasing Einstein's "all mass has energy" in a way that's appropriate for his audience by putting in the particular numbers himself. Mee's statement is a strict subset/consequence of Einstein's.